# How can I create parent-child relationships inside same table for SQL server using EF core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Here is my model `Schedule.cs`

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentScheduleId { get; set; }
        public Schedule? ParentSchedule { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Schedule>? ChildSchedules { get; set; }
```

Below is the Configuration code:

```
    public class ScheduleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Schedule>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Schedule> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(s => s.Id).UseIdentityColumn();

            builder.HasOne(x => x.ParentSchedule)
                .WithMany(x => x.ChildSchedules)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentScheduleId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

This already works on SQLite and MySql database. Is this a limitation on SQL server DBs? Or am I doing something wrong?

I get below error when I attempt to update database:

`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Schedules_Schedules_ParentScheduleId' on table 'Schedules' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

I've tried with different ON DELETE behaviour as suggested in the error message. But the outcome is same.

Comment: Did you try with `NoAction` like the error message explicitly states? I have a similar scenario with a `User` entity with `CreatedByUserId` and `UpdatedByUserId` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, MS SQL Server does not support delete/update cascades if the change cascade to the same table it originated from, or generally when there are cycles in relationships.

So the solutions here are:

- Use `ClientCascade` behavior, it will allow EF to perform cascade deletes on loaded entities even if the database does not support this.

```
 builder.HasOne(x => x.ParentSchedule)
                .WithMany(x => x.ChildSchedules)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentScheduleId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```

- Or, just use default delete behavior `ClientSetNul` (since your FK is nullable):

```
 builder.HasOne(x => x.ParentSchedule)
                .WithMany(x => x.ChildSchedules)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentScheduleId);
```